# How to reset the AWS Profiles in AWS Toolkit in VS Code

Tags: amazon-web-services, vscode-extensions, aws-toolkit

I'm using AWS Toolkit in VS Code and changed some of my Profiles. Now whenever I launch VS Code it shows that the default Profile is not valid anymore. I reinstalled AWS CLI and set up the profiles from Scratch. but there must be some nasty little config file that keeps the old profiles and serves them up each time I launch VSCode. Has anyone an idea how to reset this or where I can find such a file?

I have already checked C:/Users/Name/AppData/Roaming... but couldnt find anything. Not even deleting the AWS toolkit extension and reinstalling it changed anything..

Thank you in advance

A

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What `AWS: View AWS Toolkit Logs` command is showing you with any related errors in VSCode?

Assuming if you're able to connect to AWS using CLI, and if there is a syntax issue in your `~/.aws/credentials` or `~/.aws/config`, Toolkit may not be able to read it, even though AWS CLI can read it.

Try to clean them up under `~/.aws/`, and then reconfigure

Comment: yes, thats the funny thing. I already redid it twice. deleted the `./aws/`folder and set it up anew. No changes. therefore I thought there must be something else ....another hidden config file where the toolkit stores some configs.

Comment: Maybe try to check profile name and clean the cache in `~/.aws/cli/cache`, which cached temporary credentials. Also see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/toolkit-for-vscode/latest/userguide/setup-credentials.html

Comment: What type of credentials is it? Either AWS IAM or AWS IAM Identity Center?